# Generate list of mismatched data element Combinations between two sources

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

We receive data on a weekly and monthly basis with information regarding customers. We also sometimes have the same information stored from another source. The two sources sometimes provide contradictory information regarding customers.

How would I write a query which tells me the mismatched **CustomerId** and corresponding **Vehicle**? For example, **CustomerId** 947623 is associated with Kia in the vendor extract [Table 1] whereas we have the same customer stored as related to Hyundai [Table 2].

**Table 1**: Data received from the vendor.

| CustomerId | FirstName | LastName | Vehicle | MiscColumns |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 027548 | Jane | Doe | Honda | MiscData |
| 947623 | John | Smith | Kia | MiscData |
| 549816 | Erin | Woods | Chevy | MiscData |
| 739232 | Henry | Jackson | Ford | MiscData |

**Table 2**: Internal data records

| CustomerId | FirstName | LastName | Vehicle | MiscColumns |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 027548 | Jane | Doe | Honda | MiscData |
| 947623 | John | Smith | Hyundai | MiscData |
| 549816 | Erin | Woods | Chevy | MiscData |
| 739232 | Henry | Jackson | Ford | MiscData |

Comment: What have you tried, and what are your expected results? Is it only the Vehicle column that can vary? Which is the correct table?

Comment: You can simply join the two sources on customer ID and code where condition that checks for unequal data values. If some values might be null, you may need to use `ISNULL()` to apply place holders for the comparison or (with SQL Server 2022 or later) use the `IS DISTINCT FROM` comparison. If you also care about missing records from once source or the other, change your join to a `FULL OUTER JOIN`.

Comment: While asking a question, you need to provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example):
(1) DDL and sample data population, i.e. CREATE table(s) plus INSERT T-SQL statements. 
(2) What you need to do, i.e. logic and your code attempt implementation of it in T-SQL. 
(3) Desired output, based on the sample data in the #1 above.
(4) Your SQL Server version (SELECT @@version;).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please try the following solution.

It will work starting from SQL Server 2016 onwards.

**SQL**

```
-- DDL and sample data population, start
DECLARE @TableA TABLE (CustomerId CHAR(6) PRIMARY KEY, FirstName VARCHAR(100), LastName VARCHAR(100), Vehicle VARCHAR(100));
DECLARE @TableB table (CustomerId CHAR(6) PRIMARY KEY, FirstName VARCHAR(100), LastName VARCHAR(100), Vehicle VARCHAR(100));

INSERT INTO @TableA (CustomerId, FirstName, LastName, Vehicle) VALUES
('027548', 'Jane', 'Doe', 'Honda'),
('947623', 'John', 'Smith', 'Kia'), 
('549816', 'Erin', 'Woods', 'Chevy'),
('739232', 'Henry', 'Jackson', 'Ford'); 

INSERT INTO @TableB (CustomerId, FirstName, LastName, Vehicle) VALUES
('027548', 'Jane', 'Doe', 'Honda'),
('947623', 'John', 'Smith', 'Hyundai'), 
('549816', 'Erin', 'Woods', 'Chevy'),
('739232', 'Henry', 'Jackson', 'Ford'); 
-- DDL and sample data population, end

SELECT CustomerId
      ,[key] AS [column]
      ,Org_Value = MAX( CASE WHEN Src=1 THEN Value END)
      ,New_Value = MAX( CASE WHEN Src=2 THEN Value END)
FROM (
        SELECT Src=1
              ,CustomerId 
              ,B.*
         FROM @TableA A
         CROSS APPLY ( SELECT [Key]
                             ,COALESCE(Value, '') AS Value
                       FROM OpenJson( (SELECT A.* For JSON Path,Without_Array_Wrapper,INCLUDE_NULL_VALUES)) 
                     ) AS B
        UNION ALL
        SELECT Src=2
              ,CustomerId 
              ,B.*
         FROM @TableB A
         CROSS APPLY ( SELECT [Key]
                             ,COALESCE(Value, '') AS Value
                       FROM OpenJson( (SELECT A.* For JSON Path,Without_Array_Wrapper,INCLUDE_NULL_VALUES)) 
                     ) AS B
      ) AS A
GROUP BY CustomerId,[key]
HAVING MAX(CASE WHEN Src=1 THEN Value END)
     <> MAX(CASE WHEN Src=2 THEN Value END)
ORDER BY CustomerId,[key];
```

**Output**

| CustomerId | column | Org_Value | New_Value |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 947623 | Vehicle | Kia | Hyundai |

Comment: This worked perfectly for what I needed. It generates a list of all matches too but that should be easy to remove.

In regard to your above comment, I was unaware of the proper etiquette for posting these questions. I appreciate your short and concise explanation of what I'd need to share in the future!